# Kantu create HTML autorun page

Tags: kantu

I'm trying to create HTML autorun page from Kantu on Firefox. However, I'm getting this error every time:

To run test suite from HTML file, you need to enable "Allow access to file URLs" in the extension details page

Can anybody tell how to enable this access on firefox? I'm using Kantu version 3.7.2

Comment: Any help pleaese?

Answer (score 0):

Html Autorun file only runs macros.As far as I know firefox can access files without permission.

> file:///**/path/to/html_autorun.html**?direct=1?macro=?**Macro_name**&closeKantu=0&savelog=kantu_log.txt

Sorry for formatting by the way.